# React Native release Stuck at app:mergeReleaseResources

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, apk

I am trying to build release apk for a react native app. I have created keystore and also added the info in the `build.gradle` file as suggested in the docs.

But It is getting stuck at `app:mergeReleaseResources` for 30-40 mins no results. I have tried with different apps, the one's which used to built in the past but its not working now. 
I even tried reinstalling Android Studio and SDK but its still stuck.

Please help.

here is the log -

```

```
gradlew.bat assembleRelease
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
downloadRobolectricDependencies F:\Projects\react-native\Zest\android\build/robolectric-dependencies
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-navigation:processReleaseManifest
:react-native-splash-screen:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-splash-screen:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-splash-screen:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-splash-screen:processReleaseManifest
:react-native-vector-icons:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-vector-icons:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-vector-icons:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseAidl
:react-native-splash-screen:compileReleaseAidl
:react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:react-native-navigation:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:react-native-splash-screen:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:react-native-vector-icons:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:react-native-navigation:mergeReleaseShaders
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseShaders
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseAssets
:react-native-navigation:packageReleaseAssets
:react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseShaders
:react-native-splash-screen:compileReleaseShaders
:react-native-splash-screen:generateReleaseAssets
:react-native-splash-screen:packageReleaseAssets
:react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseShaders
:react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseShaders
:react-native-vector-icons:generateReleaseAssets
:react-native-vector-icons:packageReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseRenderscript
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseResValues
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-navigation:packageReleaseResources
:react-native-splash-screen:compileReleaseRenderscript
:react-native-splash-screen:generateReleaseResValues
:react-native-splash-screen:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-splash-screen:packageReleaseResources
:react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseRenderscript
:react-native-vector-icons:generateReleaseResValues
:react-native-vector-icons:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-vector-icons:packageReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
```

Comment: can you share your tracelog?

Comment: I have added logs... @VinayRathod

Comment: have you done this? `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Comment: send me log till end..   to BUILD FAILED..    
`:react-native-vector-icons:packageReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources`

Comment: There is no build failed message. It just stuck there...

Comment: please check your resources may be there is image which will not allow by android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android {
// ...
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
// ...
}
```

Try using this code on your app module `build.gradle:`

Comment: It worked, i don't have enough words to thanks you. 
Can you please explain how and why ?
Been stuck since yesterday!

Comment: It means Android studio DO NOT check PNG strictly. may be due to some images from resources

Comment: Oh, so that was the issue. Due to some png resources

Comment: It works with no error... but there wasn't APK in the build... any idea on that